# Parsing jsonb data in Postgresql Returns Null

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to get the total_amount field in a jsonb formatted string in a table called "data_table".

I have tried this:

```
SELECT id, service_groups->>'total_amount' as pricing FROM data_table WHERE id = 'ef5d5366-f049-4d88-8f03-1f7c0faeeb8d'
```

It returns null for pricing. However in the original string it is actually 8.5:

```
[{"label": "instant", "currency": "SGD", "route_id": "cc20991a-36bc-4ebd-ade8-f14f1a38b0d0", "selected": true, "tax_amount": 0.0, "cutoff_time": "23:59", "gross_amount": 8.5, "total_amount": 8.5, "organizations": [{"id": "f894897d-8412-49c9-8443-48f1baca1aaa", "name": "Teleportal", "price": 6.0, "weight": 1.0, "tier_id": "2517c57e-99ad-4e75-bdfc-5e6439884b68", "services": ["last-mile"], "min_price": 8.0, "base_price": 0.0, "tax_amount": 0.0, "cutoff_time": "23:59", "gross_amount": 8.0, "total_amount": 8.0, "base_min_price": 0.0, "organization_id": "d25dbd90-bba2-4453-91c8-f2dc592b3da5", "estimated_duration": 1.0}], "discount_amount": 0.0, "insurance_amount": 0.0, "estimated_duration": 1.0, "estimated_delivery_on": "2021-02-03", "service_provider_gross_amount": 8.0, "service_provider_total_amount": 8.0, "service_provider_discount_amount": 0.0}]
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adress the first array element with `-> 0` since your data is embedded into an array:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=10b9da70a4774f9fade042c0e609b943)

```
SELECT data -> 0 ->> 'total_amount'
```